# Серверы или сервера?

Tags: словообразование

В русскоязычном IT-сообществе отсутствует сложившаяся традиция по образованию формы множественного числа слова "сервер": `наши серверы` или `наши сервера`?

Второй вариант ("наши сервера́"), субъективно, встречается чаще. Выдача гугла косвенно это подтверждает.

Викисловарь, грамота.ру и прочие онлайн-сервисы дают противоречивые показания по этому вопросу.

Правомерно ли суждение, что "сервера" является просторечной/разговорной формой, а в высоком стиле (официальные документы, и, например, тексты резюме или вакансий) предпочтительнее форма "серверы" (ср.: кабели/кабеля, тексты/текста, анкеры/анкера, etc.)?

Comment: Когда безграмотные люди формируют язык,
возможны и такие варианты:
принтерА, телевизорА, емкостЯ (вместо 'ёмкости')
(мн. число, им. падеж).
Профессионалы, применяющие в своей речи подобные
слова, не очень хорошо знают русский язык.

Answer (score 4):

Каленчук М. Л., Касаткин Л. Л., Касаткина Р. Ф.  **"Большой орфоэпический словарь русского языка. Литературное произношение и ударение начала ХХI века: норма и её варианты"** , М.: АСТ-ПРЕСС КНИГА, 2012:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А ведь это хороший источник. Можно признать достаточно авторитетным. Путь не по авторам, но хотя бы по своему назначению.

Answer (score 3):

Думаю, грамматический словарь Зализняка сейчас в авторитете, всё-таки рекомендован учебным заведениям.

Там се́рвер,се́рверы,се́рверов,се́рверам, и т.д., а  сервера́, серверо́в, сервера́м, сервера́ми, сервера́х)-разговорный вариант,как драйверы/драйвера,инженеры/инженера, диспетчеры/диспетчера, корректоры/корректора, лекторы/лектора и др.

http://www.classes.ru/all-russian/dictionary-russian-paradigm-term-66305.htm

Comment: Людмила, Зализняк - это, конечно, хорошо. Но "драйвера" - это убийственно даже для моего испорченного слуха. К своему стыду, этого словаря я в руках не держал, но вообще у Зализняка общий принцип - давать все форму, даже самые экзотические. Так что при всем его авторитете, не могу априори согласиться с его рекомендациями. Словарь именно что ***грамматический***. От орфоэпии далек.

Comment: "диск с драйвер**а**ми" - сплошь и рядом, к сожалению

Comment: Да, согласен. Что могу только добавить, что это творительный падеж, а он по моим наблюдениям в русском языке самый подверженный новомодным искажениям.

Comment: Посмотрите, slava1947 подходящий словарь нашел. Орфоэпический, никуда не деться. –

Answer (score 2):

Я не очень понял насчет "противоречивых показаний". Есть только один тип словарей, которые можно принимать за некоторый (и то не абсолютный) критерий нормативности. Это орфоэпические словари. Беда в том, что слово в русском относительно новое и в авторитетные офроэпические словари (Зарва, Аванесов) пока не попало. В этой ситуации логично считать, что ***серверы*** -нормативный общелитературный вариант, а ***сервера*** - по факту разговорный и узкопрофессиональный. Готов отстаивать это и перед IT-шниками (каковым сам и являюсь), и перед филологами (к каковым если и отношусь, то только с почтением.

Comment: Я разделяю Ваше мнение субъективно. Но как его обосновать (перед коллегами-айтишниками)?

Comment: Формально-никак. Только упрямством. ))) Логика тут может быть только такая. Регулярное окончание множественного числа - Ы. Отдельные слова, для которых допустимо или нормативно окончание А, являются исключениями и они перечислены в соответствующих словарях (орфоэпических). Пока слово тут явным образом не попало, оно не может быть таким исключением признано. Вряд ли это сгодится для IT-шника, у них свой менталитет и принципы логики... Только заставить на веру принять.

Comment: Кстати, вы мне напомнили одну вещь... Единственный случай, когда я считаю филологов неправыми в споре с IT-шниками, это ударение в сочетание "в сети" ("где?", не "куда?"). Словари рекомендуют "в с**е**ти", поскольку в остальных падежах ударение не переходит на флексию. А я сильно сомневаюсь... Хорошо бы отдельный вопрос соорудить. Дарю идею, я сегодня ленив )))

Comment: Кстати,  behemothus, словари дают оба варианта: в с**е**т**и**

Comment: Узкопрофессионально встречаются "договорА" и "осУжденные", однако не многие согласятся, что это хорошо звучит.

Comment: "Кстати, behemothus, словари дают оба варианта: в сети " -какие словари? В сет**и** можно найти все, простите за каламбур. Но не всё нужно искать.

Answer (score 2):

Из Википедии

Се́рверное програ́ммное обеспечение (се́рвер, англ. server от to serve — служить; множественное число се́рверы, в разговорном языке малограмотных людей также употребляется сервера́).

Из грамматики

1) Существительные м. и ж. рода во мн.числе И.п.  имеют основное окончание Ы/И, а сущ. ср. рода – основное окончание А/Я. В то же время вариантное окончание А/Я имеет значительное количество существительных м.р.

2)  Обратим внимание на следующую закономерность: если в начальной форме слово имеет  ненулевое окончание (стена, окно), то в Р.п. окончание нулевое (стен, окон), и наоборот: при нулевом окончании в начальной форме (стол) наблюдается ненулевое окончание ОВ в Р.п.  (столов).   Примечание. Разные окончания (нулевое и ненулевое) обеспечивают различение двух форм существительного: начальной формы и формы мн. числа Р.п. (стол – столов, но: стена – стен).

**Окончание А/Я является разговорным, так как позволяет различать формы "сЕрвера и серверА" только на слух (по ударению), а в книжной речи они различаются по окончанию.**

2)  Только вариантное окончание А имеют слова (рекомендуется запомнить): профессорА, директорА, докторА, шулерА.

Только основное окончание Ы: ректоры, лекторы, бухгалтеры, диспетчеры, снайперы, редукторы, центнеры;

В остальных случаях допускаются оба варианта: инспекторы и инспекторА,  (окончание Ы относится к нейтральному стилю, а окончание А – к разговорному стилю).

Comment: А мастер или катер чем хуже доктора? :)

Comment: Они не лучше, они одинаковые, с одной разрешенной формой: катерА, мастерА. Думаю, что здесь сказалось влияние профессионального произношения, которое вытеснило литературное.

Comment: C директорами тоже не всё просто: это не всегда люди, есть распространённый технический термин (директоры антенны как конструктивные элементы).

Comment: Окончания А/Я и Ы/И различаются не только по стилю, но и по смыслу:  лагери (политические)  и лагеря (для отдыха), учители (духовные) и учителя (в школе), образа (церк.) и образы (в литературе и искусстве), счёты (инструмент) и  счета (денежные), роды (грамматические) и рода (войск).

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос № 251799

Добрый день. Запуталась со множественным числом слова "сервер". Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно.

Ответ справочной службы русского языка

Литературная норма: сЕрверы, хотя в профессиональной речи компьютерщиков нередко можно встретить вариант серверА.

Answer (score 0):

В профессиональной речи IT-специалистов слова "се́рверы" и "сервера́" обозначают различные понятия.

Когда речь идет о серверном **оборудовании** (устройствах, *hardware*) во множественном числе, то используется слово "се́рверы".

Когда речь идет о серверном **программном обеспечении** (программных компонентах, сервисах, службах, *software*) во множественном числе, то используется слово "сервера́".

Comment: Приветствую Вас на сайте! Если считаете мою правку неверной или противоречащей Вашему замыслу, то можете ее откатить.

Comment: "У нас есть се́рверы производителя A модели B, на них развернуты сервера́ многопользовательской игры X"? Никогда не слышал.

Comment: Вполне допускаю, что слово "сервера́" может быть профессиональным жаргоном. Не слишком литературно, зато сразу понятно, о чем именно идет речь. И не надо тратить время на уточняющие вопросы, типа "Уточните, пожалуйста, говоря 'сервера́', что именно вы имеете в виду: железо или софт?"